# Text check in every page (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Using Java, I am trying to write a general check for a particular text on every page in a web application that existing tests visit. Instead of having to write it on each and every page individually, is it possible to do in one place at a high level (may be in the base class)?

```
public class BaseClassForUiTest {
                public BaseClassForUiTest() {
                       ...
                }

                public void test() throws Exception {
                       boolean isNewPage = checkIfNewPage();
                       if (isNewPage)
                             // perform a text check on the page
                }
}
```

Every test extends from `BaseClassForUiTest` and overrides the `test()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of having to write it on each and every page individually, is it possible to do in one place at a high level (may be in the base class)?

Yes, it is possible by implementing [`WebDriverEventListener`](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/) into `BaseClassForUiTest` and override event handler methods to handling the appropriate `WebDriver` events according to need in one place.

[Here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/) every method corresponds to an event. According to your requirement you need to handle  `afterNavigateTo()` method. This one is called every time the navigate to a page is completed.

You have to do perform a text checker on the page code in this method so that your code is executed every time the page navigates to some other page.

```
public class BaseClassForUiTest implements WebDriverEventListener
{

      ---------
      ---------

      public void afterNavigateTo(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
    // perform desire text checker stuff on the page here
  }
}
```

**Now Create Event Throwing WebDriver to perform your test** :-

- Create a regular WebDriver.

  ```
  FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  ```
- Now create an `EventThrowingWebDriver` using our regular `WebDriver` created above.

  ```
  EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
  ```
- Create an instance of your `eventHandler` class and register it for events using the register method of `EventFiringWebDriver` object created above as :-

  ```
  BaseClassForUiTest handler = new BaseClassForUiTest();
   eventDriver.register(handler);
  ```

Full code :-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;

public class BaseClassForUiTest {

 public void test() throws Exception {              

      FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);

      BaseClassForUiTest handler = new BaseClassForUiTest();
  eventDriver.register(handler);

      eventDriver.get("your url");

      //Now do your further stuff
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. This is good stuff. However, in all the tests we are not using any driver.get(url). Instead, we are clicking on links and buttons that in turn do the navigation. Can those be captured in a generic way at the base class level to generate any of the events offered by WebDriverEventListener?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple methods which can occurs on ever link click at navigation of the page, you need to implement it, I'm sure it will solve your problem. Thanks..:)

Comment: You are right. I can use afterClickOn() method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As for me, you'd better create a separated test class for this check using [Parameterized or JUnitParams](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/parameterized-junit-tests-with-junitparams.html) and give it a urls to run where as parameters, but it depends on what is your common approach to running tests (we run all testpack at the same time, so it's a solution for us in this situation).
Also it is seems like well-logically-separated solution

If you are going to use this check as an assertion you can rewrite your current code for this case and call for it in @Before block (but it is still not a good solution, in my opinion)

Comment: Thanks. The URLs are all dynamic URLs and thus it is impossible to have a parameterized test with URLs defined.

Comment: I am ok with having this as a before check assertion, but how to do that? How can I ask Selenium to identify a new page load?

Comment: If you want to do it in `@Before` testclass simply add an appropriate assertion. But if you want to do this after page reloads during tests (even in the middle of it) -- only some dirty hacks can help in this case, I guess =\

Comment: What kind of dirty hack? I am ok with adding a hacky solution if that works since it is not going to be a permanent addition to the suite.

Comment: You can write kind of wrapper for WebDriver.get() method, for example and do the assertion check in it